# Cookie not set by the express server

Tags: express, cookies, backend, passport.js, express-session

I made a rest api using express js, passport js which is using express-session and google oauth2 strategy. When I am testing my app in my local environment it's working fine and the cookie is set in the `application > cookie` tab and is sent over the `req headers` with the name `connect.sid`.

But the issue is when I deployed on render it's not setting the cookie and no cookie is sent over the request headers.

I am not using another frontend.

this is my express-session middleware config.

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 15 days
      domain: 'testapi.onrender.com',
      path: '/',
      sameSite: 'none',
    },
  }),
);
```

Please help I tried to find over the internet and chatgpt but not found the solution, I am new to backend. THanks in advance